# How can I hide/show my toolbar item when a button is selected/deselected?

Tags: swift

I made a navigation bar with three buttons - ***Plans***,***Visit*** and ***Documents*** and every time a button is selected/clicked a view is added as a child into a container view (Code for the other buttons are similar)

---

```
@IBAction func planAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let newPlan = sender.frame.origin.x
        scrollView.subviews.forEach{$0.removeFromSuperview()}
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlansViewController2") as! PlansViewController2
        addChildView(viewController: nextController, in: scrollView)
        self.movingView.frame.origin.x = newPlan
    }
```

Now I want to add a tool bar item that only shows up when ***Plans*** or ***Documents*** is selected and disappears when ***Visit*** is selected.

At the moment I add my tool bar item in the viewDidLoad method:

```
self.toolbarItems = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Kategorienliste", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCategoryListTap(sender:)))]
```

How can I add a ***toolbarItem*** when a certain button is selected and remove it when another button is selected? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your UIBarButtonItem with a custom view like:

```
let button = UIButton()    
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
self.toolbarItems = [barButtonItem]
```

to hide / show you can access the button as the following:

```
let barButtonItem = self.toolbarItems.first
barButtonItem.customView?.isHidden = true
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Appreciated but I don´t get your code. I´m lagging at the moment. How does a custom view help me in my case? At the moment I created the tab bar item in the viewDidLoad with ***self.toolbarItems = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Kategorienliste", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCategoryListTap(sender:)))]***